# How can I translate my Html pages using my resx files

Tags: html, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, localization

I have a question about translation in Xamarin iOS. I have HTML pages that I would like to translate based on my resx files. For that I have several localization files depending on the language.

[image: resources]

For example for the error.html page

[image]

[image]

I would like to replace the

```
    <h1>Error loading page.</h1>
```

with the key contained in my localization file that would replace this key by its value. Is it possible to do that with specific html tags?

Comment: Maybe you can have a try with **Razor**.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/razor-html-templates/#what-is-razor